# Directive attribute forces boolean to string

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass a value to my directive without isolating its scope.

My directive has a link function to grab the value of the attribute:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

    scope.myAttributeValue = attrs.myAttribute;

}
```

I would like to do

```
<directive my-attribute="{{true}}"></directive>
```

When I pass a boolean value to `my-attribute`, it gets converted to a string.

How can I pass a boolean value to `my-attribute`?

Comment: Have you tried just `my-attribute="true"`? Also, you have a misspelling in your link function (myAtribute is missing a t). You might need to use `scope.myAttributeValue = attrs.myAttribute !== 'false';`.

Comment: A possible approach would be to try to add boolean logic to force it to be a boolean instead of string? e.g. true == true

Comment: What binding are you using for scope.myAttribute? @, = or &. Check in your attribute signature. If you are using @, the value is passing as a String.

Comment: @Danielo, welle none since I'm note definig a scope for my directive...

Comment: attrs has strings. use scope: { myAttribute: '=' }, and corrects the typo too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scope.$eval`:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return function linkFn(scope,elem,attrs) {
        var x = scope.$eval(attrs.myDirective);
        console.log(x);
        console.log(typeof x);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <p my-directive="true"></p>
</div>
```

The [$eval() method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) evaluates a string as an [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and will retain the type.

Avoid using interpolation (double curly brackets `{{true}}`) as that converts the Angular Expression to a string.

For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope.Scope API Reference --$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/of13j99e/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare value with a boolean and value will be converted in boolean :

For exemple

```
scope.myAttributeValue = attrs.myAttribute == true;

console.log(typeof scope.myAttributeValue);
console.log(scope.myAttributeValue);
```

Hope that helps !